# Definition of Projective space $P^{n}(\Bbb{R})$.

Tags: manifolds, definition, projective-space

The Projective Space - 
Definition 1:

The underlying set is the set $P^{n}(\Bbb{R})$ of lines in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ passing through the origin. There is another way of looking at $P^{n}(\Bbb{R})$.

On $\Bbb{R}^{n+1} - {0}$ we introduce the equivalence relation", defined as follows:
$x R y <=> \lambda x = y$ with $\lambda \in \Bbb{R},\lambda \neq 0$

Definition 2:

An equivalence class $[x]$ containing $x \in \Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ can be identified with the line through the origin in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ joining any point in the equivalence class.

I am trying to understand how definiton 2 is equivalent to definition1 or how can I understand definition 2 from definition 1?

Comment: defintion 1 is lines through the origin. Definition 2 is lines through the origin. What's the problem?

Comment: Oh you mean: why are the points related via $x\sim \lambda x$ all collinear? well, they're in the same line...

Comment: I donot understand this part - "line through the origin in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ joining any point in the equivalence class."

Comment: It would have been sufficient if we mention this - "An equivalence class $[x]$ containing $x∈\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ can be identified with the line through the origin in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ "?

Comment: Is it not clear that the set of points $\{\lambda x\}$ is a line through the origin?